# How can we loop through text files in a folder, copy the first 2 rows in each file, and transpose the results?

Tags: python, python-3.x, transpose

I have around 3000 text files in a folder.  I want to iterate through each one, get the file name of each, then copy the first two rows, do a transpose, and past the next results under the prior results?

One file has fields that look like this.

```
IDRSSD   RIAD0497                           RIAD4042                                RIAD4136            RIAD4141                    RIAD4146                               RIAD4461
         ADVERTISING & MARKETING EXPENSES   RENT & OTHER INCOME FR OTHR REAL EST    DIRECTORS FEES      LEGAL FEES & EXPENSES       FDIC DEPOSIT INSURANCE ASSESSMENTS     1ST ITEMIZED AMT OV25% OF ITEM 4078
```

I want to transform that, into this.

```
file                                                                code        field
C:\Users\ryans\Downloads\FFIEC CDR Call Schedule RIE 03312001.txt   IDRSSD  
C:\Users\ryans\Downloads\FFIEC CDR Call Schedule RIE 03312001.txt   RIAD0497    ADVERTISING & MARKETING EXPENSES
C:\Users\ryans\Downloads\FFIEC CDR Call Schedule RIE 03312001.txt   RIAD4042    RENT & OTHER INCOME FR OTHR REAL EST
C:\Users\ryans\Downloads\FFIEC CDR Call Schedule RIE 03312001.txt   RIAD4136    DIRECTORS FEES
C:\Users\ryans\Downloads\FFIEC CDR Call Schedule RIE 03312001.txt   RIAD4141    LEGAL FEES & EXPENSES
C:\Users\ryans\Downloads\FFIEC CDR Call Schedule RIE 03312001.txt   RIAD4146    FDIC DEPOSIT INSURANCE ASSESSMENTS
C:\Users\ryans\Downloads\FFIEC CDR Call Schedule RIE 03312001.txt   RIAD4461    1ST ITEMIZED AMT OV25% OF ITEM 4078
```

I have a code sample that copies/pastes the first two rows, from each file, but it doesn't do the transpose.  I think the final version of code would look something like this...

```
### mapping table for regulatory line items
import pandas as pd
import csv
import glob
import os

# Use a list here rather than a dataframe
results=[]
filelist = glob.glob("C:\\Users\\ryans\\Downloads\\*.txt")
number_of_lines = 2

for filename in filelist:
    with open(filename) as myfile:
        lines = myfile.readlines() # you can add strip() or other methods here
        file_lines = []
        print(file_lines)
        for line in lines[:2]:
            df = pd.DataFrame(lines[:2])
            transposed = df.T
            file_lines.append(transposed)
        results.append([filename, *file_lines])
        
# You can build a dataframe from that list at the end if you desire
results_df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(results, columns=['filename', 'file_lines_1', 'file_lines_2'])
```

But something is off here.  It seems to produce a bunch of empty lists.  Not sure what's going on here.  Any thoughts on how I can get the results that I'm after?  Thanks.

Comment: may be use dictionary and pandas to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

```
for filename in filelist:
    with open(filename) as myfile:
        lines = myfile.readlines() # you can add strip() or other methods here
        file_lines = []
        for line in lines[:2]:
            file_lines.append(line)
        results.append([filename, *file_lines])
```

number_of_lines = 2 <- this is an un-needed variable

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, AgentJRock, but this doesn't transpose the results.  It copies and appends the next records under the prior records.  I wan to transpose the results, or pivot the results, like I showed in the image.